# iTunes to iPhone cannot sync parts of the iTunes music library

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music, macos

I'm using iTunes on Windows and I have my Music Library. Recently I added some music (Mafia II soundtrack I purchased with the game) to the local iTunes Library, but the neither the Artist, nor the Album turn up in the Music Sync overview. Can someone tell me what might be the issue here?

Edit:
The Soundtrack in Question is the Mafia II Soundtrack acquired through the Digital Deluxe Steam Version. The Files are all in MP3 Format and to my knowledge properly tagged.

I primarily tried adding it by hand (dragging it into iTunes) and by adding them via the Add Folder/File to Library buttons. I disabled iTunes ability to manage the folders itself, as that is a behavior I do not want.

However, now, after removing and readding the tracks to the library several times, the Album itself ("2K Games - MAFIA II Official Orchestral Score") appears in the Album overview of the Music Sync menu (and there only). When looking for the ID3 Tag of the Genre ("Soundtrack") or the Contributing Artists ("2K Czech / FILMharmonic Orchestra Prague") and Album Artist ("2K Games"), nothing can be found. This changes my initial question to a small extent, but the problem, in a way, remains: It can't be found in 2 out of 3 overviews of my iTunes library.

Comment: where was the soundtrack purchased and what format is it in?

Comment: Ok, we get that you can't search to find them. But are they visible? Can you just scroll through your list and see them? Can you play the tracks in any other audio player besides iTunes? Do they play in Quicktime?

In my experience, I have found a couple instances that even though the songs were in the correct MP3 format they simply WOULD NOT play for whatever reason. I fixed this issue by using iTunes to re-encode the songs in an MP3 format. You might want to try using iTunes to convert the songs to mp3 again. (or some other lossless format)

Comment: Searching these items yields the same result as just browsing through them. By searching I meant both of these actions, browsing and using the search function. These tracks DO play in iTunes.

Comment: Maybe if you added a few screenshots to illustrate your question...

Comment: A screenshot of something not being found?

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the music to iTunes? Did you drag and drop it into the iTunes windows itself or did you manually add the music to the local folder?

If you manually added the music to the to the local folder then you need to "re-sync" your iTunes library so that the music appears in iTunes application.

Just choose "Add Folder to Library" and choose your iTunes music folder so that it "re-syncs" your library and ALSO adds all the new songs to your list as well.

[image]

You can add songs manually to your iTunes music folder without them appearing in iTunes if you navigate to the iTunes music folder itself on your computer and just drop the music in. iTunes tells you in the preferences:

[image]

But all of this is irrelevant until you tell us how you added the music to your computer???????

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I manually sync my iTunes library?

Comment: If re-syncing the library means to delete the library and recreate it like I've seen here http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2009/06/ipod-resynch-itunes-apple-library-copy.html then this is EXACTLY one of the things I want to avoid.

Comment: Hey, try taking a chill pill and stop flipping out over the completely wrong thing before I get a chance to respond. GEESH

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a codec issue and, if that's the case, you'd need to re-encode them to an [accepted format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes#File_format_support) (basically: mpeg, wave, aiff and apple's). But that usually comes along with an **error message** once you try to add it or play it on iTunes.

If you can actually play the music on iTunes only, but can't sync them to iPhone, most likely you have an issue on the phone, which usually is solely related to lack of **free space**.

Comment: There is enough free space on the Phone, the music is in proper format, apart from that I was partially able to find the tracks in the sync menu now!